# HTTP response not receiving all data while using custom Web Proxy

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

So I am making a Web Proxy that grabs an HTTP request, makes sure that GET/POST/HEAD is capitalized, and fixes the path in the first line:

```
-------------------
------REQUEST------
-------------------
GET http://boundlessecho.com/story.html HTTP/1.1
Host: boundlessecho.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


Port 80 Connected
-------------------
---FIXED REQUEST---
-------------------
GET /story.html HTTP/1.1
Host: boundlessecho.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

It then sends this data to the server specified after a DNS request which grabs the host name and the port number (99 times out of 100, no port is specified so it goes to port 80 which is the default HTTP port).

Afterwards, I am sending the HTTP response from the server back to the client/browser; however, many times, it gets caught in the receiving the HTTP response portion.

```
BufferedReader feedback = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestedServer.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter showData = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

String line;
String header = "";

while (!(line = feedback.readLine()).equals("")) {
    header += line + "\n";
}

int length = getLengthOfData(header);

showData.write(header, 0, header.length());
showData.write("\n", 0, 1);
showData.flush();

DataInputStream getBodyData = new DataInputStream(requestedServer.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream sendBodyData = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

if (length != -1) {
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    getBodyData.read(b, 0, length);
    sendBodyData.write(b, 0, length);
    sendBodyData.flush();
}

sendData.close();
showData.close();
feedback.close();
sendBodyData.close();
getBodyData.close();
```

Method to find Content-Length:

```
// Simply returns the Content-Length as an integer
public int getLengthOfData(String header) {

    if (header.indexOf("Content-Length:") == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(header.substring(header.indexOf("Content-Length:") + 16, header.indexOf("\n", header.indexOf("Content-Length:"))));

}
```

Does anyone know why it is getting stuck on feedback.readLine() or if there is a problem elsewhere in my code that would be causing this?

Note: It only gets stuck on certain requests. Some requests work!

Note 2: Code updated from original post.

Note 3: Code updated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reading of the response is incomplete. You need to read the response headers first (read until you reach a `CRLF CRLF` pair denoting the end of the headers), and then you need to analyze the headers to know if and how you should read any further data.  `HEAD` responses, and all `1xx`, `204`, and `304` response, DO NOT have body content, so do not try to read bodies for them.  Anything else has a body, and its length is dependent on the particular values of the `Transfer-Encoding`, `Content-Length`, and `Context-Type` response headers, so you need to look at them and act accordingly.

Read [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for more details and the exact rules you have to follow.

Essentially, you have to implement the following logic:

```
Read and parse HTTP headers
if not successful:
    throw error
if response can contain message body:
    if HTTP version is 1.1+ and Transfer-encoding is not identity:
        while true:
            read line, extract delimited ASCII hexadecimal, the chunk size
            if not successful:
                throw error
             if chunk size is 0:
                break while loop
             read chunk size number of bytes
        read and parse trailing HTTP headers
    else if Content-Length is specified:
        read Content-Length number of bytes
    else if Content-Type is "multipart/byteranges":
        read and parse MIME-encoded chunks until terminating MIME boundary is reached
    else:
        read until connection is closed
```

Comment: This helps a lot thank you. Do you have suggestions on how to read until the CRLF CRLF? This does mean`\r\n\r\n` correct?

Comment: Actually, did some research and discovered that the line before the data is `\r\n`. However, when I do this: `if (line.equals("\r\n")) break;`. The while loop continues until it collects all of the data and then breaks. Why isn't it picking up the line before the data?

Comment: `readLine()` handles the CRLF internally. The returned `String` does not include the CRLF. What you can do is simply loop the `readLine()` until it returns a blank `String` value, saving each non-blank line in a list, and then break the loop when the blank `String` is encountered. You can then analyze the content of the gathered list and finish reading the rest of the data accordingly.

Comment: Okay now I'm stuck on the Content-Length specification. I parsed through the header and took the Integer out of the Content-Length: field which in my case happens to be 6482. Next, I am reading 6482 bytes by creating a new `DataInputStream`  and sending the data into a byte array and writing this array to the client socket; however, it ends up sending the middle portion of the HTTP data response and the rest disappears.

Comment: @LoganJahnke: Are you sending the received headers before sending the byte array? The client is expecting a full HTTP response from your proxy. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35730428/edit) to show your updated code.

Comment: Updated the code. So in addition to the data, I need to also send the header to the client socket?

Comment: @LoganJahnke Of course you do. An HTTP response consists of headers, a blank line, and an optional body.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I still have the problem of the input only returning about half of the body data instead of all of it.

Comment: You are reading the response data into a `char[]` array, not a `byte[]` array. Remember that a `char` is 2 bytes in Java, not 1 byte. The value of the `Content-Length` header is expressed in bytes, not characters. There is also no need to copy the array into a `String` just to send it, you should be sending the array as-is. In fact, you shouldn't even be using `Reader`/`Writer` objects to handle the HTTP *body data* at all, since it is not textual data, it is binary data. Use `InputStream`/`OutputStream` objects instead.

Comment: Alright, so I switched to an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` for receiving/sending the _body data_. I still have a problem when getting the bytes from the server; it is starting in the middle of the body data. Does this have something to do with the fact that I already opened up a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Possibly, yes, if the `BufferedReader` had already started reading some of the body data while you were still reading headers from it. Try using a `BufferedInputStream` on top of the socket `InputStream`, and then use a non-buffered `InputStreamReader` on top of the `BufferedInputStream` when reading just the headers, and then go back to the `BufferedInputStream` when reading the body data. Do similar for the output to the client - client `OutputStream` <- `BufferedOutputStream` <- `OutputStreamWriter` (headers only)

Comment: Or, you could simply stop trying to implement HTTP manually and use something like [`HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) and [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead, let them do all the heavy work for you.

Comment: Can `HttpServer` and `HttpURLConnection` just send the client the data from the server? I have to go through my Web Proxy. You have been amazingly helpful by the way. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105070/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-logan-jahnke).